# How to insert a span tag into wp_list_categories

Tags: wordpress

Right now I'm using this in my `sidebar.php`

```
<?php wp_list_categories('title_li='); ?>
```

It outputs:

```
<li><a href="#">cat 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">cat 2</a></li>
<li>
    <a href="#">cat 3</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">sub cat 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">sub cat 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">sub cat 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

What I need is:

```
<li><span></span><a href="#">cat 1</a></li>
<li><span></span><a href="#">cat 2</a></li>
<li>
    <span></span><a href="#">cat 3</a>
    <ul>
        <li><span></span><a href="#">sub cat 1</a></li>
        <li><span></span><a href="#">sub cat 2</a></li>
        <li><span></span><a href="#">sub cat 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Is it doable? I'm not looking for CSS/JS solutions.

**Edit:** updated to point out the sub cat structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could accomplish that by constructing the links yourself:

```
<?php
$cats = get_categories();
$output = "<ul>\n";
foreach ($cats as $cat) {
    $name = $cat->name;
    $output .= "<li><span></span><a href=\"#\">$name</a></li>\n";
}
$output .= "</ul>\n";
echo $output;
?>
```

If you prefer, you could also just echo the output as you go, of insert this code in a function in your functions.php and call it wherever you want.

The function get_categories() gets the same categories s wp_list_categories but doesn't construct the HTML.

EDIT: You should be able to use recursion to handle sub-categories:

```
<?php
function showCats($cats) {
    $output = "<ul>\n";
    foreach ($cats as $cat) {
        $name = $cat->name;
        $output .= "<li><span></span><a href=\"#\">$name</a>";

        $children = get_categories( array('parent' => $cat->cat_ID) );
        if (count($children) > 0) {
            $output .= showCats($children);
        }

        $output .= "</li>\n";
    }
    $output .= "</ul>\n";
    return $output;
}

$cats = get_categories( array('parent' => 0) );
echo showCats($cats);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You might also find something handy in the [docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories#Examples) for `wp_list_categories`

Alternatively you could try [`get_categories`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories) instead.

or something like this: using [`get_terms`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms). **EDITED** to include sub categories

```
<?php       
$cat_args = array ( 'parent' => 0 ) ;
        $parentcategories = get_terms ( "category", $cat_args ) ;
        $no_of_categories = count ( $parentcategories ) ;

    if ( $no_of_categories > 0 ) {

        foreach ( $parentcategories as $parentcategory ) {

        echo '<ul><li><span></span><a href="'.get_term_link( $parentcategory ).'">' . $parentcategory ->name . '</a>' ;

                $parent_id = $parentcategory ->term_id;
                $subcategories = get_terms ( 'category', array ( 'child_of' => $parent_id, 'hide_empty' => false ) ) ;

            foreach ( $subcategories as $subcategory ) { 

                $args = array (
                    'post_type'=> 'category',
                    'orderby'=> 'title',
                    'order'=> 'ASC',
                    'post_per_page'=> -1,
                    'nopaging'=> 'true',
                    'taxonomy_name'=> $subcategory->name
                ); 

                echo '<ul><li><span></span><a href="'.get_term_link( $subcategory ).'">' . $subcategory->name . '</a><ul>';

                    query_posts ( $args ) ;

                        while ( have_posts () ) : the_post () ;

                            ?> 
                                <li><a href="<?php the_permalink () ; ?>"><?php the_title () ; ?></a></li>
                            <?php

                        endwhile;

                    wp_reset_query () ;

                echo '</ul></li></ul>' ; 

            } 

            echo '</li></ul>' ;

            }
    }
?>
```